# Grouping a Pandas Dataframe by Date with Python and Plotting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a comma separated file that I am reading with Pandas via Python. Here is a subset:

```
Location   Time                 Value1 Value2 
CCNY       2013-01-01 00:00:00  59     12.71    
CCNY       2013-01-01 01:00:00  96     10.6 
CCNY       2013-01-01 02:00:00  105    11.94    
CCNY       2013-01-01 03:00:00  81     11.73    
CCNY       2013-01-01 04:00:00  60     13.05    
CCNY       2013-01-01 05:00:00  51     13.25
... 
CCNY       2013-31-01 06:00:00  28     13.03
```

I need to plot value1 (x-axis) vs value2 (y-axis), but I need to do it for each day. So, for this portion of the file which contains values for the entire month of January, there will be 31 plots.

How should I go about this?

(The ultimate goal is to get best fit lines in each plot and r squared values.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below - this groups the data by day and produce a plot for each.

```
df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.day).plot(x='Value1', y='Value2')
```

Comment: Thanks @chrisb. Is there a certain way I need to read the file for this to work? I am only using parse_dates=True, index_col=1.

Comment: @alldayiwonder Depends on what you get when you read the file in ?

Answer (score 1):

Your csv looks like a fixed width file so I would use `read_fwf`, you then need to rename the time column as it treats the time portion as an unnamed column, you can then use @chrisB's answer to achieve what you want:

```
In [35]:

t="""Location   Time                 Value1 Value2 
CCNY       2013-01-01 00:00:00  59     12.71    
CCNY       2013-01-01 01:00:00  96     10.6 
CCNY       2013-01-01 02:00:00  105    11.94    
CCNY       2013-01-02 03:00:00  81     11.73    
CCNY       2013-01-02 04:00:00  60     13.05    
CCNY       2013-01-02 05:00:00  51     13.25"""
​
df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t), parse_dates=[[1,2]])
df.rename(columns={'Time_Unnamed: 2':'Time'},inplace=True)
df
Out[35]:
                 Time Location  Value1  Value2
0 2013-01-01 00:00:00     CCNY      59   12.71
1 2013-01-01 01:00:00     CCNY      96   10.60
2 2013-01-01 02:00:00     CCNY     105   11.94
3 2013-01-02 03:00:00     CCNY      81   11.73
4 2013-01-02 04:00:00     CCNY      60   13.05
5 2013-01-02 05:00:00     CCNY      51   13.25
In [36]:

df.groupby(df['Time'].dt.date).plot(x='Value1', y='Value2')
Out[36]:
2013-01-01    Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
2013-01-02    Axes(0.125,0.125;0.775x0.775)
dtype: object
```

Results in the plots:

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: it's actually a comma separated file, but that's roughly how pandas outputs the data frame to the screen.. and the time of "2013-01-01 00:00:00" is being read into a single column.

Comment: OK, i thought your snippet was an actual post of the raw data, if it's comma separated then `pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=[1], index_col=[1])` should work